# angular 2 input field validation - 1 alphabet and 8 numbers required (Custom Validation)

Tags: angular, validation, input

i need to accept **one alphabet** and **8 number** (total 9) in an input,
how can i validate this,how to perform custom validations
i have tried the pattern and maxlength,it does not meet the requirement

```
...............   
 <input type="text" name="din"  pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*$"  maxlength="9"  class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="storeData.din" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"  required> 
................
```

with my limited knowledge in this, i can't find one solution.

Also How can i set another field with pattern like 1234-123456 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need 1 letter followed by 8 numbers you could try this pattern:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{1}\d{8}$
```

Example:

https://regex101.com/r/4O59tA/1

**EDIT:** If you need 1 letter anywhere

You could leave the maxLenght atribute and use this for the pattern:

```
^\d*[a-zA-Z]{1}\d*$
```

It will match exactly one letter that is preceded by any number of digits and followed by any number of digits. This rexeg will not enforce string lenght to 9 chars, so you must use the maxLenght and minLenght atribute.

https://regex101.com/r/4O59tA/1

Comment: thanks for the answer, The alphabet can come anywhere on the 9 letter input, but 1 alphabet only accepted

Comment: Edited the answer

Comment: Np, just make sure to set the minLenght too

Comment: how we can get 1234-123456789 , that is hyphen only in 4th

Comment: ^\d{4}-\d{9}$ - 4 digits then hyphen then 9 digits